# re.sub dataframe on python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to re.sub urls(like https or http) with re.sub regex function
this is the data inside data.csv:

```
    username     timestamp        text
    xx            18:09           httpsasdadsa what
    xxx           18:09           httpsasdadsa where
    xxxx          18:07           httpsasdadsa when
```

my code :

```
import string
string.punctuation
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

for i in range (0-4586):
    data = (df['text'][i])
    x = re.sub("^https"," ", str(data))
    df['text'][i]= x
```

but it doing nothing, nothing change.
i want to do like this after the re.sub:

```
  username     timestamp        text
0 xx           18:09           what
1 xxx          18:09           where
2 xxxx         18:07           when
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a dataframe:

```
df
    username    timestamp   text
0   xx          18:09       httpsasdadsa what
1   xxx         18:09       httpsasdadsa where
2   xxxx        18:07       httpsasdadsa when
```

Then you may try [pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df.loc[df.index<4586,"text"] = df.loc[df.index<4586,"text"].str.replace("^https.*\s","")
df

    username    timestamp   text
0   xx          18:09       what
1   xxx         18:09       where
2   xxxx        18:07       when
```

Comment: its still nothing change, dont kwno why. anything else? thanks for helping tho. appriciate so much

Comment: What is the output of your `df.index` ?

Comment: i'm running it on spyder, so if i try to write code after
df.loc[df.index<4586,"text"] = df.loc[df.index<4586,"text"].str.replace("^https.*\s","")
like this : print(df.index)
it give me output : RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4586, step=1)

Comment: Try `df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace("^https.*\s","")`

Comment: still the same sir. :|

Comment: There is something wrong how you execute the code and access results in spyder. Try the same in Python console and see it's working.

Comment: i tried in console too, it just the same, and I don't know why, Thanks fo helping.

Comment: Provide the full code you execute in *console* (start to finish)

Comment: ```
import string
    string.punctuation
    import pandas as pd



    df = pd.read_csv('D:\ss\data.csv')
    df.loc[df.index<4586,"text"] = df.loc[df.index<4586,"text"].str.replace("^http"," ")
    df
    df.to_csv ('D:\ss\data.csv', index = None, header=True)
```

Comment: Look, what is the result of `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_csv('D:\ss\data.csv'); print(df.shape); print(df.columns)` ?

Comment: (4586, 4)
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'username', 'timestamp', 'text'], dtype='object')

Comment: Do you see string replacement after: `import pandas as pd; df = pd.read_csv('D:\ss\data.csv'); df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace("^https.*\s",""); print(df.head())` ?

Comment: OH ITS ACTUALLY WORKS! thank you sir.
but the sentence with https in the middle of sentence doesnt work, do you any answer if the case like that? (https in the middle of sentence)

Comment: You need to provide a *representative* sample of your data.... and what you want out of it. see [mcve] for more....

Comment: Try `df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace("^.*http.*\s","")`

Comment: it works but in all cases, if the text of http is at the last sentence ex: (something something something https:asdsada) the text before that is gone too.
ty somuch sorry asking to much until right now

Comment: df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace("^.*http.*\s|\s.*http.*\s|\s.*http.*$",""). You may think about upvoting too...

Comment: already upvote for the answer but cant upvote the comment because i'm new here sir sorry for that. but the upvote answer not show after 15 upvote system said. i really thank you for ALL the answer.

Comment: `df["text"].str.replace("(^|\s)[\w]*http[\w]*(\s|$)","")`

Comment: FWIW the reference guide for pandas.Series.str.replace is https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html